# Flutter : Deleting a custom widget that is dynamically created and stored in a list?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

The user creates tags (for example 'python') which are represented as a custom widget (called a tag) made up of a gestureDetector for a container showing the text and the container has a little 'x' red circle at the top left to delete it.

[image]

The Tags are stored in a tags List variables called tags.

[image]

In the definition of the Tag widget, I specify the name and the ontap function to delete it.

[image]

In the UI where the tags are entered, the code specifies a function (add_tag) to add the tag to the UI and the function to delete them.

[image]

and are added to the UI using the three dots methods seen here.

[image]

My problem is that I do not know how to specify to my deleteTag function which index to remove, which tag to delete.

I tried to use the ListView.builder and nothing happens in the UI when I add a tag.

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: When you changed the data, did you remember to setState to inform the view?

Comment: Hi Randal, yes when I add a widget, I do. My problem is that I don't know how to use the listview.builder with a widget defined elsewhere and where the widgets in the listview are stored in a List<Widget>tags list. I don't know how to write the builder for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use ListView.builder for this, in your build method you get access to the current index. Generate the widget inside the builder and use the index to delete the specific widget.

Comment: Thanks @Ozan for sharing I tried this and unfortunately nothing shows up in the UI when I add a tag. I edited the article to show how I use the builder.

Comment: No, you need to create your tag widget inside the build method. Somewhere in your code you get a list of tags, you give the ListView.builder the itemCount to tags.length and in your builder you create Tag widget.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having is that the ListView.Builder was feeding off a List (prebuilt, I guess, in a way) instead of a List containing the data the builder needs to build the widgets. Once I changed my tags array to contain the tag names instead of the whole tag widget, things cleared up. Thank you both!